# Disabling a plugin lead to styles being shown as plain text

Tags: plugins, text

After disabling a Plugin "PW Grid/List Post Layout For Visual Composer" by Proword the styles of the plugin are shown as plain text on the webpage.

[image]

[image]

What could cause such behavior? I have already tried to disable other plugins but it just doesn't go away.

The Plugin had to be disabled because it was interupting the Menu on mobile devices. The menu had no functionality because of it.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin uses the shortcodes you see there to generate markup. You've disabled the plugin, so now the shortcodes do not fire and only display as plain text. Either re-enable the plugin so the shortcodes start working again, or leave it disabled and find another way to achieve the layout you want to get from the plugin.